# Finding when a certain signal has a particular value in Modelsim using tcl

Tags: tcl, modelsim, questasim

I'm trying to speed up debugging. In a large trace I'm search for particular values of a signal. Im using QuestaSim 10.0b under linux.

I already found out that can be done in Modelsim/QuestaSim with the following command

```
searchlog -expr { stream == 'h20 } 0
```

Unfortunately this also matches the signal 'stream' when it has the value 'XX', but I only want it to match 0x20. How can I make sure it only matches the hex value, but not the undefined value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much searching and trying around I found the following solution.

```
searchlog -expr { stream == 'h20 && ! stream'hasX } 0
```

It seems weird to me that, if you search for a value you also have to make sure that it is not 'X', but it works.

I still hope to see more answers here.